# How do I programmatically close a simple_dialog window

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm in D7

I open a simple dialog window with the [simple dialog](http://drupal.org/project/simple_dialog) module, and i want to close the dialog programmatically.

I've tried this

```
// not working !
jQuery('#simple-dialog-container').dialog('close');
```

and this

```
jQuery(document).find('div.ui-dialog').remove();
jQuery(document).find('div.ui-widget-overlay').remove();
//This seems to work because the window disappears, but I can not open it again.
```

The X icon on the top-right do this proprely, but i can't catch the action

Thank you for help

Comment: Because its already in an iframe, you need to find another way to do that. Like injecting js to iframe, may be drupal have a way, and i dont now that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code using jquery,

```
jQuery('#simple-dialog-container').trigger('click');
```

change id/class to anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks monymirza, it works !

```
jQuery('.ui-icon-closethick').trigger('click');
//or
//jQuery('.ui-icon-closethick').click();
```